# keeping grids spaced in python when using multiple frames

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I'm trying to get my top frame to have equal spacing between all three labels.  I don't want to hard code widths of "invisible" labels to separate them because the bottom frame may need to expand the window size later.
Right now, the left label is left then there is a huge gray area that doesn't appear to belong to any of the labels, then finally the center and right labels are crunched on the right side.  Is there a better way to do this?

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

#Build buttons    
def create_buttons():
    for y in range(6):
        for x in range(6):
            ttk.Button(bot_frame, width = 5, text = str(x) + "," + str(y)).grid(column = x, row = y, sticky = W)

root = Tk()

#top frame
top_frame = ttk.Frame(root, padding = "4 4 4 4")
top_frame.grid(column = 0, row = 0, sticky = (N, E, S, W))
top_frame.columnconfigure(0, weight = 1)
top_frame.rowconfigure(0, weight = 1)
top_frame['borderwidth'] = 2
top_frame['relief'] = 'sunken'

#bottom frame
bot_frame = ttk.Frame(root, padding = "4 4 4 4")
bot_frame.grid(column = 0, row = 2, sticky = (N, E, S, W))
bot_frame.columnconfigure(0, weight = 1)
bot_frame.rowconfigure(0, weight = 1)
bot_frame['borderwidth'] = 2
bot_frame['relief'] = 'sunken'

#Top labels
left_lbl = ttk.Label(top_frame, background = 'black', foreground = 'green', width = 5, text = "left").grid(column = 0, row = 0, sticky = (N, W))
center_lbl = ttk.Label(top_frame, background = 'red', width = 6, text = 'center').grid(column = 1, row = 0, sticky = (N, E, S, W))
right_lbl = ttk.Label(top_frame, background = 'black', foreground = 'green', width = 5, text = "right").grid(column = 2, row = 0, sticky = (N, E))

create_buttons()

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest solution is to give all three columns in the top frame an equal weight. That means that each will fill up an equal amount of extra space. As written in the question the first column is defined to take up all of the extra horizontal space.

You'll also want to use tkinter Label widgets rather than ttk label widgets if you want this to work cross-platform. On the mac, for instance, the background is ignored for the ttk widgets.

For me, when I have widgets laid out in a single row or single column I find that pack works best. However, make the changes I suggest and grid works fine, too.

Grid is really great for laying things out in a grid, obviously, but it does mean that you have to take the extra steps of assigning weights to your rows and columns if you want everything to work right when the window changes size.

Comment: Thanks for the assistance.  I just picked up tkinter last week and this had been bugging me.